# How can I count the number of movies that are being watched in every hour when I have a dataframe that contains movies start and end times?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
start_timestamp        end_timestamp
2012-11-18 05:53:36.0  2012-11-18 7:46:40.0
2012-11-18 06:34:23.0  2012-12-18 09:21:57.0
```

And I want the output to look like:

```
hour                   moves_being_played
2012-11-18 05:00:00.0  1
2012-11-18 06:00:00.0  2
2012-11-18 07:00:00.0  2
2012-11-18 08:00:00.0  1
2012-11-18 09:00:00.0  1
```

The only way I can think of doing this would involve creating a table that looks like:

```
hour                   moves_being_played
2012-11-18 05:00:00.0  NA
2012-11-18 06:00:00.0  NA
2012-11-18 07:00:00.0  NA
2012-11-18 08:00:00.0  NA
2012-11-18 09:00:00.0  NA
```

And then using a for loop which iterates through every hour in the given period and seeing how many `start_timestamps` are lower and paired with an `end_timestamp` that's greater, but that seems incredibly inefficient.

Comment: It's not _that_ bad: `sapply(seq(trunc(min(df$start_timestamp), 'hour'), max(df$end_timestamp), by = 'hour'), function(x){sum(x >= df$start_timestamp & x <= df$end_timestamp)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@alistaire's comment is a succinct, performant solution and prbly shld both be an actual answer and definitely the accepted one if made into an answer.

Tossing this one out there to show a general idiom for similar, but more complex, situations (there aren't enough `do()` examples out there IMO:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(
  start_timestamp=as.POSIXct(c("2012-11-18 05:53:36.0", "2012-11-18 06:34:23.0")),
  end_timestamp=as.POSIXct(c("2012-11-18 07:46:40.0", "2012-11-18 09:21:57.0"))
)

hourly_count <- function(x) {

  range(x$start_timestamp, x$end_timestamp) %>%
    format("%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") %>%
    as.POSIXct()-> rng

  hrs <- seq(from=rng[1], to=rng[2], by="1 hour")

  data_frame(hour=hrs, is_playing=TRUE)

}

rowwise(df) %>%
  do(hourly_count(.)) %>%
  count(hour, is_playing) %>%
  select(-is_playing, movies_being_played=n)
## Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
## Groups: hour [5]
## 
##                  hour movies_being_played
##                <dttm>               <int>
## 1 2012-11-18 05:00:00                   1
## 2 2012-11-18 06:00:00                   2
## 3 2012-11-18 07:00:00                   2
## 4 2012-11-18 08:00:00                   1
## 5 2012-11-18 09:00:00                   1
```

Comment: Much more elegant than what I was envisioning!